# How can I make cout faster?

Tags: c++, performance, console-application, cout, dev-c++

Is there any way to make this run faster and still do the same thing?

```
#include <iostream>

int box[80][20];

void drawbox()
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            std::cout << char(box[x][y]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    drawbox();
    return(0);
}
```

IDE: DEV C++ || OS: Windows

Comment: Probably be faster to build up a string and output that once, or once per outer loop, which'd be 1 or 20 couts, rather than 20*80=1600

Comment: @Marc B: A buffered I/O library is supposed to take care of that for you.  Unfortunately, C++ iostreams are dog slow at both buffering and I/O.  Look at the questions I've asked if you want to see some nice benchmarks showing just how miserable they are.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - And it's really disappointing.  They could be faster than C's stdio library if they had been designed more carefully.  :-(

Comment: @Marc B:  Why not make that a real answer?

Comment: Buffering helps with the actual I/O itself but function calls are generally _not_ cost-free. Twenty outputs with eighty characters each will almost certainly be faster that sixteen hundred with one character each. Not because it's actually sending those character to a _device,_ just because it's constructing and tearing down stack frames, among other things.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I definitely agree (at least compared to `printf` which has to parse format strings -- I don't think iostreams could beat the performance of `putc` and `puts` although it should have been able to match them).

Comment: @Drew: because I was just guessing. I've never written so much as line 1 of a C++ program in my life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marc B said in the comments, putting the output into a string first *should* be faster:

```
int box[80][20];

void drawbox()
{
    std::string str = "";
    str.reserve(80 * 20);

    for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            str += char(box[x][y]);
        }
    }

    std::cout << str << std::flush;
}
```

Comment: oh, do preallocate that string.  `std::string` doesn't necessarily have optimized allocation patterns like say `std::vector`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'd be very disappointed if it was necessary... this definitely sounds like a quality of implementation issue...

Comment: @ Matthieu M: I doubt that any default string implementation reserves 1600 bytes. Thus it is likely there will be multiple re-allocations before finish writing. Just a good idea to pre-reserve the space required.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to declare the `box` array differently:

```
char box[20][81];
```

Then you can `cout` a row at a time. If you can't do this for whatever reason, then there's no need to use std::string here -- a `char` array is faster:

```
char row[81] ; row[80] = 0 ;
for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
  {
  for (int x = 0 ; x < 80 ; x++)
    row[x] = char(box[x][y]) ;
  std::cout << row ;
  // Don't you want a newline here?
  }
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. No need to dynamically allocate an array that's the same size every time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use `putchar` from `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Mark: really?  Are you sure it's your program that's the bottleneck and not the console window?  Can you check if it's faster when output is redirected to a file?

Comment: The issue here is not using C++ vs. C. (And in fact, in his example it would be putchar() from cstdio). The issue is printing data for every character.

Comment: @Bjoern: `putchar` is buffered, it should be quite fast compared to actually drawing the text on the screen.

Comment: C++ io functions are buffered as well.

Comment: @Ed: yes, but they require a function call (not inlined because they are virtual) unless you have a very clever linker and LTO is activated (and even then, it might not work). I don't know if `putchar` is inline or not.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Only `overflow()` of `streambuf` is virtual. Most calls to the `std::ostream/char` version of `op<<` (a free function) shouldn't involve a virtual function call.